# Error al cargar la URI de una imagen android

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Tengo una aplicación que da la opción de seleccionar una imagen de tu galería y luego mostrarla en un ImageView, luego a esa URI de la imagen obtenida de la galería la transformo en un String y la guardo en mi SharedPreferences.
El problema es cuando inicio nuevamente la aplicación y cuando quiero cargar la imagen recuperada de mi SharedPreferences me muestra el siguiente error y mi aplicación crashea:
**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{e25faa9 9233:com.bigoblog.mytodolist/u0a154} (pid=9233, uid=10154) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs**

Este es mi código de cuando abro la galería:

```
private fun openImagePicker() {
        //Creates an intent for redeem into the gallery :D
        val iGallery = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
            data = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        }

        startActivityForResult(iGallery, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY)
    }

    //This method waits for the image from the gallery :D
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        /*The first 'if' checks if it was succesfull to open an activity, the other one, checks if this request is to
         open the gallery
         */
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
                imgProfile.setImageURI(data?.data)
                imageWasSelected = true

                //Storing the string of the URI into the SharedPreferences.
                stringURI = data?.dataString!!
                Log.i("STRING_DATA", data.dataString!!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es mi código al recuperar la StringUri que guardé en mi sharedpreferences:

```
private fun renderProfile() {
        val profilePictureUri = spManager.getString("KEY_PROFILE_PICTURE") 


        if(profilePictureUri.isEmpty()) mBinding.imageUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person) //Si no se ha guardado una foto, poner ic_person por defecto
        else mBinding.imageUser.setImageURI(Uri.parse(profilePictureUri)) //En esta linea de código tengo el error que mencioné arriba
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje:

> "requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related
> APIs"

indica que por seguridad, solo puedes agregar la imagen al recibir la información en onActivityResult():

```
//This method waits for the image from the gallery :D
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
        imageWasSelected = true
         if(data != null){ // Set image!
            binding.imgProfile.setImageURI(data?.data)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

si tratas de guardar la Uri en preferencias y después cargar la imagen usando `.setImageURI(...)`, esto no se permite por seguridad.

Comment: Hay alguna otra forma de guardar la imagen dentro de la memoria en ese caso?